# Not displayed SVG elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I try generate `<rect/>` elements in my page:

```
<svg style="width:1920px; height:1080px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

This code:

```
var w = $("svg").width();
var h = $("svg").height();
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < w; i += 30) {
        for (var j = 0; j < h; j += 30) {
            $("svg").append('<rect x=' + i + ' y=' + j + ' width="30px" height="30px" style="stroke: black; fill: none;" />');
        }
    }
});
```

And it does not displayed on page, but I see them in DOM in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the problem felix pointed out, I think the problem is in the way jquery creates new DOM elements that do not work well with SVG (or namespaced elements), you can do it be setting the innerHTML of the SVG or something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var w = $("svg").width();
    var h = $("svg").height();
    var html = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < w; i += 30) {
        for (var j = 0; j < h; j += 30) {
            html += '<rect x=' + i + ' y=' + j + ' width="30px" height="30px" style="stroke: black; fill: none;" />';
        }
    }

    $("svg").html(html);
});
```

If you want to manipulate SVGs I'd recommend you look into something like [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) that gives you a lot more tools to work with SVGs

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `w` anf `h` variable inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var w = $("svg").width();
    var h = $("svg").height();
    for (var i = 0; i < w; i += 30) {
        for (var j = 0; j < h; j += 30) {
            $("svg").append('<rect x=' + i + ' y=' + j + ' width="30px" height="30px" style="stroke: black; fill: none;" />');
        }
    }
});
```